# How to keep only the recent date in sql and delete the rest from the table based on conditions?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a SQL table and my data looks like this:

```
PAN_NO |NIFTY_TREND | COUNT_OF_TREND | PURCHASE_DATE | NEW_SCH_CODE

XXX    |    011     |      1         |   29-SEP-16   |    168
YYY    |    111     |      1         |   02-JUN-17   |    168
ZZZ    |    011     |      3         |   27-OCT-14   |    178
ZZZ    |    011     |      3         |   28-JUN-17   |    168
ZZZ    |    011     |      3         |   28-JUN-17   |     04
```

Condition for expected output:

For each pan if the count_of_trend is greater than 1 then i should keep the record which has the recent
purchase date and remove the rest. If the recent purchase date is also the same anyone among the 2 can be selected.

```
Expected Output :

PAN_NO |NIFTY_TREND | COUNT_OF_TREND | PURCHASE_DATE | NEW_SCH_CODE

XXX    |    011     |      1         |   29-SEP-16   |    168
YYY    |    111     |      1         |   02-JUN-17   |    168
ZZZ    |    011     |      3         |   28-JUN-17   |    168
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
select pan_no, nifty_trend, count_of_trend, max(purchase_date) over (partition by pan_no)
from table group by pan_no having count_of_trend >1
```

but the above code doesnt work.

I am performing all of this in sql developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it looks like this:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (pan_no, nifty_trent, count_of_trend, purchase_date, new_sch_code) as
  2    (select 'xxx', '011', 1, date '2016-09-29', 168 from dual union all
  3     select 'yyy', '111', 1, date '2017-06-02', 168 from dual union all
  4     select 'zzz', '011', 3, date '2014-10-27', 178 from dual union all
  5     select 'zzz', '011', 3, date '2017-06-28', 168 from dual union all
  6     select 'zzz', '011', 3, date '2017-06-28',   4 from dual
  7    ),
```

Query begins here; `temp` CTE "sorts" rows for each `pan_no` by `purchase_date` in descending order; the final `select` then returns either rows whose `rn = 1` (i.e. they rank as the "highest"), or `count_of_trend = 1` (because *sorting* has to be applied only to rows whose `count_of_trend` is larger than 1).

```
  8  temp as
  9    (select t.*,
 10       row_number() over (partition by pan_no order by purchase_date desc) rn
 11     from test t
 12    )
 13  select pan_no, nifty_trent, count_of_trend, purchase_date, new_sch_code
 14  from temp
 15  where rn = 1
 16     or count_of_trend = 1;

PAN NIF COUNT_OF_TREND PURCHASE_D NEW_SCH_CODE
--- --- -------------- ---------- ------------
xxx 011              1 29.09.2016          168
yyy 111              1 02.06.2017          168
zzz 011              3 28.06.2017            4

SQL>
```